# Axis: faultString: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file

Tags: java, iis, web-services, axis

I have deployed a webservice using servletexec configured with IIS and i can successfully access webservice using anonymous account. But when I enable Windows Integrated Authentication I am getting following error.

```
  - ntlm authentication scheme selected
- Discarding unexpected response: HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file.
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}hostname:akvm

org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file.
    at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.createFault(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:222)
    at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.endElement(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:129)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.endElement(DeserializationContext.java:1087)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:633)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:719)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1685)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:368)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:834)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:764)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:148)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1242)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:375)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.parse(DeserializationContext.java:227)
    at org.apache.axis.SOAPPart.getAsSOAPEnvelope(SOAPPart.java:696)
    at org.apache.axis.Message.getSOAPEnvelope(Message.java:435)
    at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.MustUnderstandChecker.invoke(MustUnderstandChecker.java:62)
    at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:206)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that the Axis client does not like the NTLM authentication challenge.  See error message at the top:

```
Discarding unexpected response: HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
```

After which there is no XML for Axis to parse, which is why you're getting premature end of file.

In order to use NTLM with Axis (1.4), you'll have to use the `CommonsHTTPSender` instead of the standard transport:

```
<transport name="http" pivot="java:org.apache.axis.transport.http.CommonsHTTPSender">
</transport>
```

in your `client-config.wsdd` and then set up the NTLM username and password through the `Stub` object.

Answer (score 0):

The "premature end of file" type errors from the xerces SAX implementation usually indicates that the SAX parser expected data, but got none (not `null`, but an initialized empty `InputSource`). From the stack trace, it looks as if the axis SOAP handler expects a SOAP xml message to arrive, but the message is empty. My knowledge of ISS and its infrastructure is close to nil, can you get any log messages from the server?